# How do I know the message id and request id when setting SQS as eventbridge rule target?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, aws-event-bridge

I have created an Eventbridge rule which has SQS standard queue as the target. All events come to the Eventbridge will be forwarded to the SQS queue. Every event comes to SQS queue has messageId and requestId which I can get from consumers who receiving the event. However, I don't have access to some of the consumers. How can I get the messageId and requestId from EventBridge?

I have EventBridge logs but it only tells me the events go through the EventBus, it doesn't give me the MessageId and requestId.

Comment: I am pretty sure you don't. Why would you care about either of them? What are you trying to achieve here and why? In particular the requestId - what requestId are you referring to? From what request?

Comment: the reason is that I found missing events from my consumer. I need to find who else is consuming from this queue. If I get the messageId, I can ask AWS support to check that.

Comment: Then add a queue policy and deny anyone the permission to read from the queue except for the one type of consumer you know and see if something changes.